# MVVM: How to access Data from View.xaml.cs-File

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hello everyone as mentioned in a previous post which is thankfully sloved I encountered a second problem. In my WPF application I had to implement certain code sections for the camera-transmission and line drawing in the View.xaml.cs file instead of in the ViewModel.cs File. Is there a possibility to access functions from the View.xaml.cs File out of the ViewModel.cs File and also the other way around?
Thanks for you great support so far!

**FunctionGeneratorView.xaml.cs**

```
namespace VirtualLab.MVVM.Views
{
    public partial class FunctionGeneratorView : UserControl
    {
        static string functionGeneratorCamAddress = @"@device:pnp:\\?\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
        bool isConnectedVideo = false;

        public FunctionGeneratorView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Video
         private void startVideo()
         {
            try
            {
                videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(functionGeneratorCamAddress);
                videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(VideoSource_NewFrame);
                videoSource.Start();
                //Console.WriteLine("Video eingeschaltet");
                //MessageBox.Show("Video eingeschaltet");
                this.isConnectedVideo = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen");
                MessageBox.Show("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen");
            }
         }

        private void stopVideo()
        {
            videoSource.SignalToStop();
            videoSource = null;
            videoFuncGen.Source = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Video ausgeschaltet");
            MessageBox.Show("Video ausgeschaltet");
            this.isConnectedVideo = false;
        }

        private void toggleVideo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(this.isConnectedVideo))
            {
                this.startVideo();
            }
            else
            {
                this.stopVideo();
            }
        }

        void VideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
             try
             {
                 System.Drawing.Image img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

                 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                 img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                 ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                 BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                 bi.BeginInit();
                 bi.StreamSource = ms;
                 bi.EndInit();

                 bi.Freeze();
                 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                 {
                     videoFuncGen.Source = bi;
                 }));
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen");
                MessageBox.Show("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="VirtualLab.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VirtualLab"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:VirtualLab.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:VirtualLab.MVVM.Views"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/MenuButtonTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/FuncGenButtonStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/OsziButtonTheme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CircuitViewModel}">
                <views:CircuitView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:OszilloskopViewModel}">
                <views:OszilloskopView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FunctionGeneratorViewModel}">
                <views:FunctionGeneratorView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: "in a previous post which is thankfully sloved" - if your question is solved, you should accept the answer which provided the solution, if such answer exists

Comment: "Is there a possibility to access functions from the View.xaml.cs File out of the ViewModel.cs" - it won't be mvvm

Comment: @ASh I know, that this would violate the concept of MVVM unfortunately. However, is there a way to access the functions of the .xaml.cs-File from a File of another Folder?

Comment: Have you considered adding `ICommand`s to yout viewmodel to handle starting and stopping of a video? This might also enable you to move `videoSource` and related fields to the viewmodel.